# Just Cause 2 mercenary mode increased difficulty when completing settlements

Tags: just-cause-2

I have finished the story mode of Just Cause 2. Now I'm plowing through the settlements (aiming for a level of completion). However, the speed and ferocity in which the Panauan army defends these settlements seems to have increased dramatically. Can anyone explain why...?

Comment: self-fulfilling prophecy?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The game is not, in specific, harder in Mercenary mode.  However, two things may be causing your apparent increase in difficulty:

1. As you generate more chaos overall in the process of unlocking the story missions, you increase your maximum Heat level.  This can lead to a much more rapid and strong response from the Panuan military.
2. When you venture into new areas, you may be in zones where you have not damaged the Panuan infrastructure as much.  Taking out enemy communications arrays, air fields, and military leaders can make a noticeable difference in the enemy's response time.

Comment: Point two is exactly the point to make. Great answer, Xemu.

Comment: You're absolutely spot on in Point #2. In a zone where I've disrupted most of the communications and infrastructure, I get far less of a reaction when I blow up a communications outpost. I've noticed that if I venture into an area that I haven't cleared the infrastructure from (or started to) the reaction from the military is much more severe (especially the number of choppers sent after me).

Answer (score 0):

Some people say that Mercenary Mode has it's own difficulty mode, harder than story mode.
Personally I have finished story mode on the hardest difficulty and did't notice much of increase in Mercenary Mode, but I did't play much after finishing the game.