# How can I make the military's life harder?   (In Just Cause 2, that is)

Tags: just-cause-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How, and When, do resource constraints affect Just Cause 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8710/how-and-when-do-resource-constraints-affect-just-cause-2)

So I've been playing Just Cause 2 for a little while now, and what I've discovered is that the military really doesn't like me too much.  In fact, they keep sending men to kill me!

I'm interested in preventing that from happening.  As Xemu mentioned in his answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1516/just-cause-2-mercenary-mode-increased-difficulty-when-completing-settlements/3503#3503), it is possible to decrease the military's effectiveness by blowing up various elements of their infrastructure.

I've blown up comm towers and gotten a "Enemy communications disrupted" message, and I've killed Colonels and gotten a "Enemy morale lowered" message.  I've also blown up a few pumping stations and gotten a message about oil transportation being disrupted.  However, I have no idea what the actual in-game effects of, say, lowered enemy morale is.

What I'm wondering is: **What actions are available to decrease the effectiveness of the military and what effect does each of these actions have?**

Comment: If you changed the title to "How can I make the military's life harder?", would you get more up votes or more down votes? Certainly more views :)

Comment: Reminds me of "How do I know if a corpse is safe to eat?"

Comment: Bummer.  You're right.

Comment: @Steve I think the effect only happens if you've blown up everything in an area. Once you've achieved 100% in an area there will be no military there. It could be related to that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, I have almost 50 hours of playtime in this game, I've 100%ed well over a hundred locations, and I haven't noticed any effect at all from these "disruptions". I think it may just be flavor text. From a game design perspective, it wouldn't make much sense to give them a debilitating effect, since that would make the game gradually become easier and easier.

Comment: I would have to disagree with the second half of your answer. From a game design perspective it would make quite a bit of sense if as you blew up the different infrastructure the military response lessened. The more time you put into completing areas and destroying infrastructure the more powerful you should become, making the game 'easier'. This would counterbalance the increased threat levels granted to you after beating certain agency missions. Unfortunately I've yet to see any effect of blowing stuff up either, granted I'm at under 50% complete in mercenary mode.